# Variable value changes once operators are applied

Tags: javascript

When I run this function with the first radio button selected, the system outputs the correct value of 30. However, once I try to apply some changes to this value (for example by adding 1 to this value of 30) the system shows me 301 as a result.

I get the same issue when the radio button with value 25 is selected. Once I try to do mathematical changes, the system treats this variable as 250.

Any ideas what I am missing here? Thanks in advance.

```
<script>
function f1()
            {
...
var Ergebnis_RP = document.getElementsByName("Ergebnis_RP");
                if(Ergebnis_RP[0].checked)
                    {   var Erg = Ergebnis_RP[0].value;}

                else if(Ergebnis_RP[1].checked)
                    {   var Erg = Ergebnis_RP[1].value;}
...
    document.write(Erg);
    var Spielwert = Erg + 1;
    document.write(Spielwert);
            }
        </script>

<body>
<input type="radio" name="Ergebnis_RP" value=30>Verl. Schwarz
<input type="radio" name="Ergebnis_RP" value=25>Verl. U3
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of a textbox is always a string. You need to coerce it to a number. The easiest way to do that is:

`+Ergebnis_RP[0].value`

Be sure to do this every time you read a number from a textbox.

---

Further explanation of the issue:

When you combine two strings, they are concatenated like `"ab" + "cd" -> "abcd"`.

But when you combine different types, the second one is coerced to be the same as the first. `"ab" + 1 -> "ab" + "1" -> "ab1"`.

Your code takes a string and adds a number. The string happens to be digits but that doesn't matter. `"12" + 3 -> "12" + "3" -> "123"`.

To fix this, start with a number then add the string. `0 + "12" -> 0 + 12 -> 12`.

As a shortcut, the `+` operator acts on numbers just like the `-` operator. Consider the number `-5`. The `-` is a negation. `+` is another unary operator that takes a number and returns the same number. Sounds useless, but it has its place. `+"12" -> 12`.